# JS Asynchron script faild to execute

Tags: javascript, ads

I want to include an adserver js script with javascript and load it async. But every try ends with an warning and the script isn't executed.

I get the following error message:
"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."

I have tried to following variants:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "http://example.com/test.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Or I used the HTML Script attribute async

```
<script src="http://example.com/test.js" async></script>
```

But nothing worked, since the external script uses document.write. Is there another way to include such scripts?

How to "explicitly open" a page ("unless it is explicitly opened" - see warning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to overwrite `document.write` temporarily until the script is executed, afterwards replace original functionality.

```
var tempDocWrite = document.write;
document.write = function(el){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = el;
    document.body.appendChild(div)
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function(){
    document.write = tempDocWrite
}
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "http://example.com/test.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

note: have not tested the above code

Comment: Thank you. I get "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". Btw. in line 3 you should repleace msg with el.

Comment: Oh great work! But I have another question based on your code. See jsfiddle example (it will not work, since jsfiddle don't allow document.write at all, but just for code formating) http://jsfiddle.net/02h6ss7h/. 
How can I dynamically controll the position where the code is inserted. In your example, it is placed at the top of the page, in my example I added hardcoded the position in the function, but how can I use it with 2 differnt scripts, if I want to place script 1 in #top and script 2 in #middle?

Comment: @leftjustified that sounds like a completely different problem, I'd suggest you create a new question for that.